# How to create Hazard Risk plot (but not log(HR) with the use of smoothHR

Tags: r, smoothing

When we are looking at some HR plots produced by the smoothHR together with the plot.HR, we can see that Ln(HR) is presented in Y-axis (e.g. https://rdrr.io/cran/smoothHR/man/plot.HR.html)
I would like to create the plot of HR (but not Ln(HR)) on the given predictor, with confidence bands. How to do it? I tried to find a tool but failed. By the way, what is the reason for producing Ln(HR) plot instead of an HR plot? HR is much easier to communicate than Ln(HR).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: OK, let's take the example from https://rdrr.io/cran/smoothHR/man/plot.HR.html

`library(survival)data(whas500)`  
`fit <- coxph(Surv(lenfol, fstat)~age+hr+gender+diasbp+pspline(bmi)+pspline(los),
             data=whas500, x=TRUE)`  
`hr1 <- smoothHR(data=whas500, coxfit=fit)`  
`plot(hr1, predictor="bmi", prob=0, conf.level=0.95)`

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(hr_1, "serumAlb", prob = 0.5, conf.level = 0.95, ylab = "log HR", xlab = "Serum Albumin Levels (g/L)", ylog = FALSE)
```

The key is the prameter `ylog = FALSE`; with it, the plot uses HR as Y-axis scale.